# How to start a browser in non private mode by selenium?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome

By default, Selenium opens the browser in private mode which
causes the tester has to login again and again. This is stupid
and troublsome. Does it provide any option to avoid this?
My test machine uses Chrome browser.

Comment: private mode you mean the Chrome browser opens in an "Incognito" mode?

Comment: No. Selenium will open a browser in Incognito mode by default.
I need non Incognito mode.

Comment: Ok, just check in the ChromeOptions option.addArguments("--incognito"); and you might have been passing to the browser